# Part of website not showing text

Tags: html, safari

I've got my website for a couple of years now and suddenly a part of my website isn't showing its text..

I can see it in chrome, firefox, mobile safari etc. Except for Safari on the mac.

Its the following code;

```
    <div id="contact">
        <h1>CONTACT.</h1>
        <div class="top-divider"></div>
            <div class="content cushycms"><div id="form">
<form action="contact.php" method="post"><span>Naam</span> <input class="name" name="name" type="text" /> <span>Email</span> <input class="email" name="email" type="text" /> <span>Bericht</span><textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
<div id="phone"><span>Als je dit kan zien, niet invullen!</span> <input name="phone" type="text" /></div>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;</form>
</div>

<div id="social-footer">
<h2 class="notop">Follow me:</h2>

<p style="line-height: 150%;">Meer informatie of een offerte aanvragen? Vul links het formulier in of stuur een mailtje naar <a href="mailto:info@remydesigns.nl">info@x</a><br />
<br />
Blijf op de hoogte van al mijn werk en lopende projecten, volg mij via de onderstaande social media.</p>
```

The second part which says "Follow me" isn't showing up.

The strange part is that when i check the page offline it just shows the text, it only happens online within Safari.

Does anyone know a solution?
Thanks

**--------UPDATE---------**

Oke i figured it has something to do with the latest update of Safari (8.0.5) I checked my website on Macbook with still Safari 8.0.4 on it, and voila it shows up!

Now i need to figure out what is causing the problem in the coding, for not showing up..

Comment: check whether all tags are properly closed!!

Comment: *"The strange part is that when i check the page offline it just shows the text, it only happens online within Safari."*  you include some jquery or css from outside which is not working when you go offline.

Comment: I took out an old backup, replaced it and still won't show up. I guess it hasn't something to do with any coding..

Answer (score 0):

Remove notop and try again. maybe your class is not compatible with something.. try removing things untill it works and then you will know for sure.

Comment: I took out an old backup, replaced it and still won't show up. I guess it hasn't something to do with any coding..